# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi \over 3} \sec x\tan x\sqrt {\sec x + 2} \, dx $ using a substitution of your choice

Tags: integration

My attempt:

$$\eqalign{
  & \int_0^{\pi  \over 3} \sec x\tan x\sqrt {\sec x + 2} \, dx   \cr 
  & u = \sec x  \cr 
  & {du \over dx} = \sec x\tan x  \cr 
  & {dx \over du} = {1 \over \sec x\tan x}  \cr 
  & \int_0^{\pi  \over 3} \sec x\tan x\sqrt {\sec x + 2} \, dx  = \int_1^2 {\sec x\tan x\sqrt {u + 2} \over \sec x\tan x} \, du   \cr 
  &  = \int_1^2 \sqrt {u + 2} \, du \cr 
  &  = \int_1^2 (u + 2)^{1 \over 2} \, du   \cr 
  &  = \int_1^2 u^{1 \over 2} + \sqrt 2 \, du   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {{2 \over 3}{u^{{3 \over 2}}} + u\sqrt 2 } \right]_1^2  \cr 
  &  = \left[ {2 \over 3}(2)^{3 \over 2} + 2\sqrt 2 \right] - \left[ {2 \over 3}(1)^{3 \over 2} + \sqrt 2 \right]  \cr 
  &  = 2.633\ldots \cr} $$

---

This is the wrong answer, the right answer is ${{16} \over 3} - 2\sqrt 3 $ (1.87 in decimal form).

Could someone explain where I went wrong please?

Thank you!

Comment: $(u+2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \ne u^{\frac{1}{2}} + \sqrt{2} $

Comment: Please don't use `\limits` on the title of a question: it doesn't render prettily on the main page. Thanks.

Comment: @RandomVariable I see... is it possible to expand this out at all?
Furthermore, if I were to integrate this I'd have to do it as a function right?

Comment: Make another substitution $v=u+2$.  Or make the initial substitution that André Nicolas suggests below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=\sec x+2$. Then $du=\sec x\tan x\,dx$, so we are finding $\displaystyle\int_{u=3}^4 u^{1/2}\,du$.

**Remark:** Substitution is a much simpler technique than you make it to be. The substitution $u=\sec x$ also works nicely, in pretty much the same way, except that we end up integrating $\sqrt{u+2}\,du$. You got to that, after more time than necessary, and then made an algebra slip. Of course you know that $\sqrt{u+2}\ne \sqrt{u}+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain how I spent more time on it than necessary? I'd love to know how I could have done this faster, I really am prone to a lot of errors on other similar questions when I use substitution so your insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Assad: It is contained in my answer. We go *directly* to $du=\sec x\tan x\,dx$, and *see* that that is part of the expression we want to integrate (which is what motivated the substitution). So we *replace* $\sec x\tan x\,dx$ by $du$, replace $\sec x+2$ by $u$, and we are done. I was also recalling an earlier question I am pretty sure was from you (same style) in which substitution took a long time. Don't bother with this $\frac{dx}{du}$ stuff.

Comment: I see! I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$  \int_1^2 {{{(u + 2)}^{{1 \over 2}}}du}   \neq \int_1^2 {{u^{{1 \over 2}}} + \sqrt 2 du}  $

If this is hard to see let $v=u+2$…

Comment: I see the mistake, thank you!